# Highlight opened file in netbeans 7.2

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

Is it possible to track opened file in files window in Netbeans?
In Visual Studio there is an option "Track active item in solutions explorer" maybe there is something similar in Netbeans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in menubar: **`View -> Synchronize Editor with Views`**. If checked the current file is selected in "Projects" and "Files" and vice versa.